# Origin of じゃ as contraction of では

Tags: grammar, etymology, history

What is the origin of the contraction では→じゃ? I googled around for a bit, but I wasn't able to find any answer at all.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this article: http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/02/26/japanese-particle-combination-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-de-wa-and-%E3%81%98%E3%82%83-ja/

Comment: The article you cited does not address the origin of the contraction では→じ, but only that of では. Thank you anyway. The article was very interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contraction is simply a matter of fast speech and sound shapes.  で or `/de/` is a front-of-the-mouth sound, where [affrication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affricate_consonant#Affrication) is not uncommon.  Consider how English *don't you* often becomes *doncha* in fast speech, or how *could you* becomes *cudja*.  So too with では -- `/de wa/` → `*/dea/` → `*/d͡ʑea/` → `/d͡ʑa/`.