# じゃまた translates as 'see you later' , can anyone please explain 'jya' and it's meaning and uses?

Tags: learning, comparative-constructions

I am very interested in finding out what じゃ means in different contexts. Is it a particle, adjective, marker? If you could provide different uses and/or examples or even refer me to somewhere I can learn more I would be grateful.
Hoping someone can help me please,
Amanda

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23642/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/63244/9831

Comment: See [How to use じゃ in grammar?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53601/78) and [Origin of じゃ as contraction of では](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53662/78).